# Strange JS Variable Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game over on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/macnor44/74fdhxwp/), and I'm encountering a strange issue. No matter what the user input is and no matter what the actual outcome of the game is, two losses are being added to the respective counter. I am unable to find the source of the issue, any help would be appreciated. Counter1 tracks ties, counter2 tracks wins, counter3 (the broken one) tracks losses, and counter4 tracks games played.

```
 $('#begin').click(function() {
  playRPS();
  return false;
});

let counter1 = 0;
let counter2 = 0;
let counter3 = 0;
let counter4 = 0;

var playRPS = function() {
  var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
  var compChoice = computerChoice();
  var result = compare(userChoice, compChoice);
  track(userChoice, compChoice);
  $('body').append('<p>You chose ' + userChoice + '</p>')
    .append('<p>The computer chose ' + compChoice + '</p>')
    .append('<p>' + result + '</p>');
    document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = counter2
    document.getElementById("losses").innerHTML = counter3
    document.getElementById("ties").innerHTML = counter1
    document.getElementById("gamesPlayed").innerHTML = counter4
};

var computerChoice = function() {
  var randomNum = Math.random();
  if (randomNum < 0.0001) {
    randomNum = "bomb";
  } else if (randomNum < 0.34) {
    randomNum = "rock";
  } else if (randomNum <= 0.67) {
    randomNum = "paper";
  } else if (randomNum < 0.99) {
    randomNum = "scissors";
  } else {
    randomNum = "gun";
  }
  return randomNum;
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
  }
  if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      return "You win";
    } else {
      return "The Computer wins";
    }
  }
  if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
      return "You win";
    } else {
      return "The Computer wins";
    }
  }
  if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "paper") {
      return "You win";
    } else {
      return "The Computer wins";
    }
  }
  if (choice1 === "bomb") {
    return "You win";
  }
  if (choice2 === "bomb") {
    return "The Computer wins"
  }
  if (choice1 === "gun") {
    return "You win"
  }
  if (choice2 === "gun") {
    return "The Computer wins"
  }
};

var track = function(uChoice, cChoice) {
  if (uChoice === cChoice) {
    counter1 += 1;
  }
  if (uChoice === "rock") {
    if (cChoice === "scissors")
      counter2 += 1;
  } else {
    counter3 += 1;
  }
  if (uChoice === "paper") {
    if (cChoice === "rock")
      counter2 += 1;
  } else {
    counter3 += 1;
  }
  if (uChoice === "scissors") {
    if (cChoice === "paper")
      counter2 += 1;
  } else {
    counter3 += 1;
  }
  if (uChoice === "bomb") {
    counter2 += 1;
  }
  if (uChoice === "gun") {
    counter2 += 1;
  }
  if (cChoice === "bomb") {
    counter3 += 1;
  }
  if (cChoice === "gun") {
    counter3 += 1;
  }
  counter4 += 1;
};
```

Comment: Use `if-else-if` statements in your `track` function, not only `if-else`

Comment: Your `if` logic is off; right now, you have `if rock ... else counter3 increments`, and that statement duplicated for `paper` and `scissors`. No matter what is picked, `rock`, `paper` or `scissors`, you're gonna increment twice. Definitely gonna want some `else if` statements in that logic. Also, some variable naming conventions would help; `counter3` is meaningless, but something like `totalLosses`, etc. would definitely help improve readability.

Comment: Also as a suggestion, if you are going to write if statements without `{}`, please inline the next command so it is more readable.

Comment: Like  @TimLewis said, your if logic is the problem, check this version ive updated. https://jsfiddle.net/2b1rq09m/1

Comment: This many IF statements is always going to cause trouble, particularly when nested - as you've proved, it isn't easy to work out which ones will fire, and which `else` will fire.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that you can take.

- Fix the `track` function to use correct if-else-if statements (For which I did a quick update [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4mo80sj3/)). Consider changing your variable names which are meaningless for your counters.
- Consider changing the compare method to return an integer instead of a string (0 is tie, 1 is player wins, -1 is comp. wins). This will allow you to build the string afterwards and reuse the compare result to update your counters. You are currently doing the compare logic twice (in `compare` and in `track`)

Next, you should use a debugger or log statements to track down where the issue come from, you would've discovered this issue pretty quickly as it is very easily reproducible ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. You can probably tell, but I'm still pretty new to all this. Thanks again.